# How can my chat bubble point to the same spot on multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

It should always point to the same part of an image regardless of the size of the phone.  I thought that if I have this point for one resolution, I could calculate a ratio of x-coordinate:width and y-coordinate:height, then multiply these ratios by the screen dimensions to get my anchor point.  The image I was given is too large so I set a fixed height.  But if the image is of fixed height, the chat bubble would not point to the same part of the image.

For example, if I have one phone that is taller than the other, using the same ratio would make the chat bubble point to a taller pt in the image.  Is there a way around this?  Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Order"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wayfinder_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:src="@drawable/main_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/description_side_margins"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/description_side_margins"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/wayfinder_instructions"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wayfinder_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyButton
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_bubble"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_bottom_center"
    android:text="@string/caption"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post some images to illustrate more clearly?

Comment: to put it simply, I have a framelayout consisting of an imageview and a textview.  How do I make sure the textview always points to the same part of the image, regardless of screen size?